# How do I reload my ~/.lircrc file?

Tags: lirc

I'm trying to make a button execute a command using irexec, but it's not working.
How do I reload the lircrc file without restarting the pc or logging in/out?

Answer (score 1):

You could run `source lircrc` and it will reload any environment settings in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what source is about above, but I use the following
run a Terminal from within your X Session
ps -ef | grep irexec
kill the irexec process id
type irexec and press enter
Note this runs the process NOT in the background, thus you can easily Ctrl C to stop it, modify your .lircrc and then repeat run irexec again at the prompt